# How to access components created in Xamarin.Forms C# code behind?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, declaration, code-behind

So, I'm doing an app in Xamarin.Forms that creates some components and layouts when a button is clicked.

My problem is that I need to access these components afterwards so I can change the text in some labels, get values from editors and remove them later if necessary...

This is the piece of code that creates the components:

```
private void newItem()
{
    StackLayout add = new StackLayout { };
    add.StyleId = "add_" + posicio;
    elements.Children.Add(add);

    StackLayout grupInical = new StackLayout 
    {
        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal 
    };
    add.Children.Add(grupInical);

    Label number = new Label 
    {
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End, 
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand, 
        Text = "Element" + posicio.ToString(), 
        FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold, 
        Margin = new Thickness(5, 0, 0, 0) 
    };

    Button tancar = new Button 
    {
        Padding = new Thickness(5), 
        Text = "✕", 
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End, 
        BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent, 
        WidthRequest = 30, 
        HeightRequest = 30 
    };
    number.StyleId = "number_" + posicio;
    tancar.StyleId = "tancar_" + posicio;
    tancar.Clicked += Eliminar_clicked;

    grupInical.Children.Add(number_);
    grupInical.Children.Add(tancar);

    StackLayout values = new StackLayout 
    { 
        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal 
    };
    values.StyleId = "values" + posicio;
    add.Children.Add(values);

    Button elegir = new Button 
    {
        Text = "Element" 
    };
    Editor percentage = new Editor { MaxLength = 2, WidthRequest = 30 };

    Label desc = new Label 
    { 
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, 
        FontSize = 20, 
        FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold, 
        Text = "%" 
    };

    Picker picker = new Picker 
    {
        IsVisible = false 
    };
    elegir.Clicked += Elegir_Clicked;
    elegir.StyleId = "elegir_"+posicio;
    percentatge.StyleId = "percentatge_" + posicio;
    desc.StyleId = "desc_" + posicio;
    picker.StyleId = "picker_" + posicio;

    values.Children.Add(elegir);
    values.Children.Add(percentatge);
    values.Children.Add(desc);
    values.Children.Add(picker);
    posicio += 1;
    scroll.ScrollToAsync(0, elements.Height, true);
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to access the components by assigning them a `styleid` value but I can't access the component.

Have you got any suggestions on how to identify the items so I can reference them later on?

Comment: you should declare them at the class level instead of the local level

Answer (score 1):

Declare  these components at the class level and then you can access them in the other place in your project.

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    Label numberLabel;
    StackLayout myAddStackLayout;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        newItem()

        numberLabel.Text = "updateValue";

        myAddStackLayout.Children.Add(...);
    }

    public void test() {

        numberLabel.Text = "updateValue";

        myAddStackLayout.Children.Add(...);
    }

    private void newItem()
    {
        StackLayout add = new StackLayout { };
        Label number = new Label ();          
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are the components from xaml declared? (initialized using InitializeComponent();)

Comment: You can use x:Name to declare them in the xaml.